# Mixed block in loading JS in HTTPS redirect

Tags: php, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a PHP web site written using Laravel framework. It runs on a AWS elasticBeanstalk, standard PHP template.
I put a custom dns, www.mycompany.com and add a SSL/TLS certificate. I also force the redirect from port 80 to 443 in the load balancer configuration.

Now if I type http://www.mycompany.com I got a 301 and redirect to https://www.mycompany.com, which is the correct behaviour. If I type a sub page like http://www.mycompany.com/about I got a 301 and redirect to https://www.mycompany.com/about, still what I expected, same if I load an image.

Problem is when it loads javascript lib, as example:  http://www.mycompany.com/js/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js which actually does not redirect to https and it's blocked browser side with **Mixed block** error.

Library in PHP are loaded with relative path like this:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.textarea_autosize.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/placeholders.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Any idea how can I fix this?

**ANSWER - PROBLEM FIXED**
I just fixed putting this few line in boot function inside AppServiceProvider.php:

```
 If (env('APP_ENV') !== 'local') {
        URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
```

Comment: Could you put your update as an answer to your question? I think it would make the solution more obvious and accessible.